# SQL query for matching a column across two tables

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables: `users` & `userGroup` with data like:

**users**:

```
 user      | age | gender

    testUserA,  25,   Male
    testUserB,  30,   Female
    testUserC,  35,   Male
```

**userGroup**:

```
user     | group

testUserA, groupA
testUserB, groupA
testUserC, groupB
```

How would I phrase a query to list the male users in groupA?

Comment: You would use `JOIN` and `WHERE`.  This is pretty basic SQL.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and tell us which database you're using.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a `join` and a `where` clause to filter `gender` and `group`:

```
select u.user
from user u
join userGroup ug on u.user = ug.user
where u.gender = 'Male'
  and ug.group = 'groupA'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I haven't used SQL in a couple years and couldn't find the right command.  (I was trying to UNION it.)

Answer (score 0):

This query would join the two tables together and also filter by gender.

```
SELECT u.User, u.Gender, ug.Group
FROM user u
INNER JOIN userGroup ug
ON u.user = ug.user
WHERE u.gender = 'Male'
AND ug.Group = 'groupA';
```

Comment: You forgot the group restriction in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
select a.user, a.age, a.gender, b.group from users as a 
inner join userGroup as b on a.user=b.user 
where a.gender='Male' and b.group='groupA'
```